# ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file on windows server 2008

Tags: mysql, window

i am using mysql 5.1.34 and windows server 2008 when i try to out a csv using a procedure on mapped network drive in mysql it is showing this error (ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file on windows server 2008) but same procedure is working on local disk. is there are any setting which i have to made in mysql configuration file. to export file on mapped network drive.

by using etl tool i can able to export file on same drive.

i am having all the required rights on both windows as well as mysql.

thanks...
Jagtap C. V.

Answer (score 1):

Mapped drives on Windows are per-session. When you run this MySQL command, it is executed in the MySQL server process. The MySQL server process is running in a different session (likely as the `LOCAL SERVICE` user) than your login, so it has no access your drive mappings - hence the error.

The simplest workaround, as you have found, is using a different tool that does the disk I/O client-side (in your user session). It may also be possible to do it by using a UNC path (e.g. `\\server\share\folder\file.ext`) instead of a drive letter - but only if the MySQL server process is running as a user that the file server trusts.

Answer (score -1):

This is a WIndows permissions problem.

MySQL is probably running as a different local user (likely NOT a domain user) that does not have rights on the mapped drive.  When you run the export utility it is run with YOUR credentials and does have write access.

Comment: thnaks jim, actually i am able to access that drive i can read, delete, create, write files from that drive (manually), and i am power user in windows and using super user account in mysql. mysql is running on different server and i am trying to write file on different server where mysql is not installed .

Comment: That's what I mean.  If MySQL is running as some superuser on its computer, that account may not have write permissions on the network drive, even though you do.

Comment: The main is not permissions but simply the fact that the user's mapped drives do not exist in the session where the MySQL server process is running.